# Probability of winning at least one contest

Tags: probability

Let's say someone enters several contests and the odds of winning each are known. For example $5$ contests and the probabilities of winning are $0.1, 0.05, 0.04, 0.02,$ and $0.01.$ How would you find the probability of winning at least one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming they are independent contests, that would be
\begin{align}
1-\mathbb{P}[\text{winning none of them}] &= 1-0.9\cdot0.95\cdot0.96\cdot0.98\cdot0.99 \\
&\approx 0.20
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

> The probability of winning at least one contest is equal to $1$ minus the
>   probability of winning no contest.

The keyword is *converse probability*

Let $X$ be the random variable for the number of won contests. Then we have

$P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=3)+P(X=4)+P(X=5)=1$.

$P(X=0)+P(X\geq 1)=1$

Thus  $P(X\geq 1)=1-P(X=0)$